# VBA - file saves as tab-delimited instead of csv

Tags: file, vba, csv, format

I'm getting slightly confused by this issue. I have a macro that grabs data from one spreadsheet, re-formats it and saves in another spreadsheet. Everything works perfectly well but this piece of code seems to be working incorrectly:

```
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
        With NewBook
        .Title = "Pts"
        .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Minestar_exports\" & Pts & "", FileFormat:=xlCSV, 
 CreateBackup:=False
        .Close
        End With
```

The trouble is that it save the file all right but seems to ignore the **FileFormat:=xlCSV** bit and saves it as TAB-delimeted instead. It's no biggie, when macro finishes running I just overwrite the temporary file using proper file format but still I couldn't figure out why this is happening. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

maybe, it has to do with your Windows regional settings.
Have a look to: http://excel.tips.net/T003232_Specifying_a_Delimiter_when_Saving_a_CSV_File_in_a_Macro.html

with regards, Christian Hahn.